# Logging all requests in Node.js/Express

Tags: json, node.js, express, logging, winston

In my small node.js application, using express, I wanted to log all the incoming requests, so I ended up with this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function(app) {
   app.set("port", 50001);
   app.set("json spaces", 2);
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
      app.logger.info("received from "+req.get("X-Forwarded-For")+" : "+req.method+" "+req.originalUrl+" (Authorization: "+req.get("Authorization")+")");
      //does not work if json is malformed
      //app.logger.info("content :"+JSON.stringify(req.body));
      if (error /*instanceof SyntaxError*/) {
         res.status(400);
         app.logger.error(error);
         res.json({ error:{msg: error.message}});
      } else {
         next();
      }
   });
   app.use(app.auth.initialize());
};
```

Unfortunately, I only get the logs via the `app.logger.info` line when there's an error (in my case a malformed JSON string in the body). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Expressjs adapts its functionality based on what type of callback you give it (this is not common in JS libraries so it is not surprising that people get confused by it).

If you do this where your callback has four arguments:

```
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {...});
```

then Express assumes this is an error-only middleware handler and will only be called when there are errors.  In [the express doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), see the section labeled ***Error-handling middleware***.  Note this specific part of that page:

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other
>   middleware functions, except with four arguments instead of three,
>   specifically with the signature (err, req, res, next)):

And, here's a whole section of the documentation devoted to [error handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

If you use just three arguments:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {...});
```

then, it is a normal middleware that is called when there are not errors.  I'm not sure if they provide a single way to get both.  But, certainly as a workaround, you could put your logging code into a function and then call that function from two separate middleware handlers, one for errors and one for non-errors.

Answer (score 33):

Use morgan https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Install morgan

```
$ npm install morgan
```

Include morgan in the index.js or app.js or server.js file (The file that pointed by the script tag in the package.json)

```
var morgan = require('morgan')
```

Then add below before all the app call.

```
app.use(morgan('combined'))
```

Complete example

```
var express = require('express')
var morgan = require('morgan')

var app = express()

app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

A sample output line looks like this:

```
::1 - - [31/May/2021:09:03:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2078 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Does it log body?

Comment: It won't log body. logging body/params/query on every request will make your console untidy.

Comment: Need it for testing

Comment: @Akshay me too. Hopefully it is possible with "morgan-body" package ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991670/350384))

Comment: Over here in 2022 it looks like morgan hasn't been updated in a couple of years. How do we feel about [`express-requests-logger`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-requests-logger)?

Answer (score 11):

**`DEBUG='*'` or `DEBUG='express:router'` environment variable**

It does not show a lot of information about the request, but it does show the path and method, which might be enough for basic applications, and is convenient as it does not require any extra setup.

`DEBUG='*'` enables all logs and is slightly easier to type:

```
DEBUG='*' ./app.js
```

or the more specific `DEBUG='express:router'` is what you will generally want in a complex application with a lot of middleware, otherwise the `DEBUG='*'` could produce mountains of output:

```
DEBUG='express:router' ./app.js
```

E.g. with the hello world:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Then as I play on the browser with different URLs I can see logs such as:

```
  express:router dispatching GET / +3m
  express:router query  : / +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : / +0ms
  express:router dispatching GET /asdf +10s
  express:router query  : /asdf +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /asdf +0ms
  finalhandler default 404 +3m
  express:router dispatching GET /asdf?qwer=zxcv +17s
  express:router query  : /asdf?qwer=zxcv +0ms
  express:router expressInit  : /asdf?qwer=zxcv +0ms
  finalhandler default 404 +17s
```

Documentation at: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Tested on express 4.17.1.

Comment: For anyone using this very helpful solution on Windows, you need to omit the single quotes around the environment variable value.  E.g., I used `setx /m DEBUG express.router`, in a Command Prompt running as Administrator, to set the environment variable at a system level -- because I needed to debug a process launched by a Windows service.  This was on Windows 10 (with express 4.17.1 and nodejs 18.14.1).

If you're launching the process from a Command Prompt directly, you could just use `set DEBUG=express.router`.

Answer (score 8):

npm install body-parser

npm install morgan-body

and use this snippet,

```
const express = require('express')
const morganBody = require("morgan-body")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()
const port = 8888

// must parse body before morganBody as body will be logged
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// hook morganBody to express app
morganBody(app, {logAllReqHeader:true, maxBodyLength:5000});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')

})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use grackle_tracking npm library to easily log all your traffic out to the console or log it to your database - also tracks uncaugt/caught errors - you can toggle it on/off easily for different environments as well since it's just

```
grackle_tracking.configure({...configuration...});
app.use(grackle_tracking.track);
```

so you can comment out both or just the bottom line for environments/users you don't want to track
https://www.getgrackle.com/libraries#grackle_tracking_overview

Answer (score -6):

You could use try/catch

```
try {
   var jsonBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
   app.logger.info("content :" + jsonBody);
} catch (err) { 
    app.logger.error("content error, error type: invalid json, error msg:" + err);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the request log does not display either with a try/catch block. I edited my question to remove the part on the body content, as my real problem is the missing log when there is no error !